# jQuery random images with random times in several tds

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 4 rows and 7 columns. In each td I have placed a link (a) with three random images (created by php with no problem :)). The idea is to fadeIn and FadeOut the three images infinitely.
The thing is that I want the images from each td fade at different random times, not all at the same time.
I've tried this, but I'm quite new to jQuery.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="casella"><img src="" /><img src="" /><img src="" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="casella"><img src="" /><img src="" /><img src="" /></a></td>
    ...till 7 columns
</tr>
<tr... till 4 rows
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".casella").each(function(i,el) anim() {
 $(el "img").first().fadeOut(1500);
 $(el "img").first().fadeIn(1500);
 setTimeout(anim, 3000);
}
            anim();})
```

CSS:

```
a.casella {position:relative;} 
a.casella img{position: absolute; left:0; top:0; display:none; z-index:-1; width:120px; height:120px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".casella").each(function(i,el) anim() {
 $(el "img").first().fadeOut(1500);
 $(el "img").first().fadeIn(1500);
 setTimeout(anim, 3000);
}
            anim();})
```

It should be:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".casella").each(function anim(i,el) {
         $("img",el).first().fadeOut(1500);
         $("img",el).first().fadeIn(1500);
         setTimeout(anim, 3000);
    });
});
```

See the second line -- you had `anim()` after the arguments.

Also, i fixed the issue with the selector.

And there were more syntax errors.

Comment: :( I think there are several more syntax errors... As I said before I'm really new to jQuery and If I copy your code it doesn't work. Thanks anyway :P

Comment: I've just tried your code, but it does not work. I have a css that says: a.casella {position:relative;} a.casella img{position: absolute; left:0; top:0; display:none; z-index:-1;} And it shows no images... :(

Comment: Scimonster I think that the problem at all (besides the syntaxis ;)) is that the method to fade three images in each td is not working at all with Jquery.... is there any way to do it?

Comment: I think that the problem is in $("img, el) I need to select the three images within the "a" element. The "a" element is now "el" variable, but I do not know how to say the img within the "el"... normally you say $("el img"), but el is a variable... is there any way to point to the a element childs ??

Comment: I've tried instead of $("img",el).first().fadeOut(1500); $(el).child().first().fadeOut(1500); But it does nothing...H E L P !